# How to use Google's Sparse Hash

Tags: hash, sparse-matrix

In my project, I am asked to use Google's Sparse Hash. But I don't even know where to start. These are steps that I take and do not get my code even compiled:

- The sparsehash-1.11 code is in the same directory with where my code is.
- I typed "#include " at the beginning of my code.

The error is

```
Multiple markers at this line
- fatal error: google/sparse_hash_map: No such file or directory
- Unresolved inclusion: <google/sparse_hash_map>
```

I really don't know what to do. Waiting for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is obvious, but if your google hashmap source is already in the same directory as your code is, you should probably try:

```
#include "sparse_hash_map"
```

instead of

```
#include <google/sparse_hash_map>
```

Worse case, `include -I</directory/to/google/sparse_hash_map>` in your compile command line.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could locate *sparse_hash_set* in your computer ( **locate sparse_hash_set** ) and create a symbolic link from the directory where *sparse_hash_set* is installed to google/sparse_hash_map.

```
test@ubuntu:~# updatedb                   # To update the locate database
test@ubuntu:~# locate sparse_hash_map
/usr/include/google/sparsehash/sparse_hash_map
test@ubuntu:~# ln -s /usr/include/google/sparsehash/sparse_hash_map /usr/include/google/sparse_hash_map
```